# Streaming or REST calls for one-minute updates?

Tags: java, rest, streaming

Let's say you're sending data from IoT appliances to a central server at intervals of one minute.

This interval is NEVER going to change.

Would you go with some type of streaming, long-lived connection (which type?) or just make synchronous HTTP calls at that interval?

Comment: Streams and long-lived connection "live" in beetwen, in "59 seconds" when they are not needed and when something wrong can happen. So, I would take usual HTTP call.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make a long-lived connection.

1. if something temporary breaks you'll have to deal with the reconnection
2. you're permanently keeping a TCP connection for each appliance for nothing.

Let the appliances send an HTTP call whenever they have something to say.